# Три глагола подряд

Tags: грамотная-речь

«Предлагается рекомендовать ратифицировать положения протокола, что позволит обеспечить охрану объектов окружающей среды» - можно ли писать подряд три глагола? Как лучше?

Answer (score 1):

Лучше  - не писать.
Уж больно напоминает "Решили рискнуть начать посылать сходить купить выпить..."

Answer (score 0):

Да, можно. Составное именное или глагольное сказуемое может быть осложненным-состоять из трех или более слов.

Answer (score 0):

На мой взгляд, можно писать подряд, так как "рекомендовать ратифицировать" является в данном случае прямым дополнением.